# How to call controller action from HTML view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

In my HTML View page I am using datepicker control. I want to redirect from view to my controller "Index" action on OnSelect method of datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var datepickval = null;
    $('#Date').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (selDate) {
            // Here I want to call Action..
        }
    });      
});
```

So I don't know how to call this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
window.location.href = "/{yourcontroller}/{youraction}"
```

you can send data as querystring

```
 window.location.href = "/{yourcontroller}/{youraction}?parameter1=test&parameter2=2"
```

Comment: Yes it is working. But how to pass attributes. I mean, how to send the date to action method

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
            var datepickval = null;
            $('#Date').datepicker({
                onSelect: function (selDate) {
                    window.location.href='index'
                }
            });      
        });
</script>
```